# primefaces dialog with inputtext as parameter

Tags: jsf, input, dialog, primefaces

I would like to give the content of an inputText as a parameter to a function in a backing bean, I know that I could send the content in the backing bean, but it doesn't make much sense in my object model. I know that in the datatable, you can provide a function with the name of the "var", I thought I could use the same mechanism by passing the ID of the inputText, but it always sends null. Is there a way to do it ?

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Reason for obsolescence" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">  
    <h:form>  

       <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
           <h:outputLabel for="reason" value="Reason for obsolescence :" />  
           <p:inputText value="default"  id="reason" required="true" label="reason" />  

               <p:commandButton id="provideReason" value="Ok" update=":form:tabView:table-metadata"   
                   action="#{tableMetadataController.setSelectedObsolete(reason)}"   
                   oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>  
       </h:panelGrid>  

    </h:form>  
</p:dialog>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this in such an obscure way? Binding the value of the input to a value in the backing bean is a much better way.

Comment: Because the backing bean has nothing to do with the reason for obsolescence so it wouldn't be proper. Or I could then store the reason in a `ObsoleteEntry` which I should inject in each item that was selected for obsolescence which seems more "heavy" to me. There is also something that "bugs" me is that, say I have a function `public void setObsolete(ObsoleteEntry o)`, I would then have to rename to `setObsolete()` and perform a test to return null if the injected ObsoleteEntry is null... When looking at signatures only, the latter is less self-explanatory to me, but maybe its an SE-logic :/